# "Use of undeclared identifier 'strchr'" when building in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My Objective-C project has compiled fine up til now either in the Xcode IDE or using the following script lines:

```
xcodebuild -scheme ObjCHelper -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -xcconfig ./ObjCHelper.xcconfig clean build
echo "Built ObjCHelper for simulator"
xcodebuild -scheme ObjCHelper -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -xcconfig ObjCHelper.xcconfig clean build
echo "Built ObjCHelper for iPhone"
```

(similar for Release).
After upgrading to Xcode 12.5 (12E262), I now get many errors of the above kind.  Here is a sample from the build output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:77:9: error: no member named 'strncmp' in the global namespace
using ::strncmp;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:78:9: error: no member named 'strcoll' in the global namespace
using ::strcoll;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:79:9: error: no member named 'strxfrm' in the global namespace
using ::strxfrm;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:82:9: error: no member named 'strcspn' in the global namespace
using ::strcspn;
      ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Both the simulator and iphoneos builds fail in the same way.
It seems that part of the C++ SDK can't be found since the upgrade - how can I best mend this?

I've tried deinstalling Xcode and reinstalling it, but the problem was the same.

Edit:  It builds OK in Xcode 12.5 on a colleague's Mac.  I tried taking the version back to 12.3 anyway, but the problem is still there.

The Framework and Header Search paths are set as follows:
[image]
When I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode, I deleted Application/Xcode.app.  As far as I understand, the toolchains are here, in Contents/Developer/Toolchains.  If I've understood correctly, Xcode should not be searching for C++ files outside this location?

Comment: when you manually include those c++ headers and right click them in source in Xcode, where do you end up? And when you create a blank project and do the same, where do you end up?

Comment: In my project, when I look at string.h, I end up in the expected location, i.e. the system header search path.  Xcode is complaining about the content of string.h.

Comment: I just created a new empty project, and copied the contents of one of my Objective-C classes to the new files.  It builds without a problem.  At this point, I'm thinking of copying all the content over into a new project and just abandoning the old one.

Comment: even if this is much more work, it is kind of safe. Apart from that after all you can still compare the xcode project files which contain the scheme and build settings on command line. That way it should be obvious what was wrong. Well and then you can earn some points here by sharing what you found out. So the whole thing was not for nothing.